# New-LocalUser returns null but user account is created

Tags: powershell

I am creating a local user by running below command.

```
$LocalAccount = New-LocalUser "myaccount" -Password "*****" -FullName "My Account" -Description "My Account" -AccountNeverExpires -PasswordNeverExpires
```

According to Microsoft documentation, `New-LocalUser` command is supposed to return a `LocalUser` object.

Right after that, I am adding that account to `Administrators` group but it fails as `$LocalAccount` is null even though I can see that the account is created.

```
if ((Get-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators" -Member $LocalAccount).Count -eq 0)
{
    Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators" -Member $LocalAccount
}
```

This happens only when I run this as part of a script. If I just run     `$LocalAccount = New-LocalUser "myaccount" -Password "*****" -FullName "My Account" -Description "My Account" -AccountNeverExpires -PasswordNeverExpires`, it works fine and I can see `$LocalAccount` has new user info.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Pretty sure `-Member` is expecting a *localprincipal* object, and you're passing it a *localuser* one. Try passing it the **SID** property instead: `$LocalAccount.SID.Value`.

Comment: Code works if I execute them individually.

Comment: Can you post the rest of the code?

Comment: I cannot post rest of the code. It has nothing to do with user creation.

Comment: You can post the code, you don't want to. Those are 2 different meanings. Seems like there's an issue elsewhere if you can run the commands individually and they work. Is this being run remotely by any chance?

Comment: If it works on its own, it's most likely how its integrated into the rest of your code that is the issue. Your call.

Comment: You could also try a `New-` and then a `Get-`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is `Get-LocalGroupMember` which doesn't give you any output when run within the script. This means your `If` statement will always return false and the `Add-LocalGroupMember` is not getting executed.

Alternatively, you can add the user to the group at the time of account creation:

```
$LocalAccount = New-LocalUser "myaccount" -Password $Secure_String_Pwd -FullName "My Account" -Description "My Account" -AccountNeverExpires -PasswordNeverExpires -Verbose  | Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators" -Verbose
```

if you want to keep your original script they try using `write-output`:

```
$LocalAccount = New-LocalUser "myaccount" -Password $Secure_String_Pwd -FullName "My Account" -Description "My Account" -AccountNeverExpires -PasswordNeverExpires -Verbose


if ((Get-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators" -Member $LocalAccount  -Verbose -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue| Write-Output).Count -eq 0)
{
    Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators" -Member $LocalAccount -Verbose
}
```

Your `if` statement is not helping because the account is freshly created using `New-LocalUser` so no need to check if it is part of the `Administrators` group.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you must pass an encrypted password to New-LocalUser, so that is probably why you are not getting a return object. Also you need to use the .Name portion of the object when you perform the Add-LocalGroupMember or Get-LocalGroupMember. Also instead of '-eq 0' (which works), it's always better to use '-lt 1'.  Lastly consider using 'measure' if you are trying to get a count.

Rough working example:

```
$passwd = ("thepassword" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force)
$AddObj = (New-LocalUser "myaccount" -Password $passwd -FullName "My Account" -Description "My Account" -AccountNeverExpires -PasswordNeverExpires)
if ((Get-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators" | where-object Name -match "\\${AddObj.Name}$" | measure).Count -lt 1)
{
    Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators" -Member $AddObj.Name
}
```

- Note this is just a rough example, you need to check for the user first and also it's better to use a variable for the account id and not the object IMO.